# Append a Wordpress shortcode to a css class?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

So...

After hours of trial and error, I can't seem to get this working.

I have a plugin called woodiscuz, which allows users to comment on products (it's an e-commerce store running woocommerce, nothing fancy).

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oH5T.png

I have another plugin called myCRED, which serves as a loyalty scheme. (get points when you spend, etc)

myCRED comes with badges, and you can display a users earned badges by using [mycred_my_badges]. ***I want this badge/shortcode to appear under the STAFF badge.***

So i figured, hey why don't i just use the do_shortcode() function i learned recently... Nope.

This is the code I have tried to use:

```js
$( ".wpc-comment-left" ).append( document.createTextNode(<?php echo do_shortcode(“[mycred_my_badges]”); ?>) );
```

Now, looking at the comment screenshot, the blue box is a css class called "wpc-comment-left", hence why i'm trying to append my shortcode to it. The red part is where i want the badges to appear.

I hope this makes sense to some of you. I don't know where else to look and I know very little PHP and JS so any help is highly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the string for javascript in case of quotes etc, and wrap the generated string in quotes:

```
$( ".wpc-comment-left" ).append( document.createTextNode("<?php echo json_encode(do_shortcode("[mycred_my_badges]")); ?>") );
```

Comment: Most likely, I also recommend checking the source code how to check what php is echoing.

Comment: @janw Edited, added json_encode to ensure a string which won't close the textNode string too early if it contains a double quote.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. However, i just realised I need to display the actual comment author's badge, not the current user's badge... this shortcode only shows the current user's badge.

Comment: You can use the user_id attribute of the shortcode to specify the user whose badge you want to display. Can you provide an example of the HTML which is output by the shortcode? Then we can help you better.

Comment: @markmoxx Unfortunately development is on hold for now, and I didn't get any further on the matter. If I do it i'll try to remember to update this post.